# Chaining Multiple IF Statements in Excel to Calculate Work Shifts from Times

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, excel-2013

I am trying to calculate a work shift based on the time entered in an Excel worksheet. The shift allocation is as below:

> If Time >= 05:30 PM & <= 01:30 AM  - 1st shift
>
> If Time >= 01:30 AM & <= 09:30 AM  - 2nd shift
>
> If Time >= 09:30 AM & <= 01:30 AM  - 3rd shift

I am using IF AND conditions but still it's showing incorrect results. Below is the formula I am using.

```
=IF(AND(D2>=TIMEVALUE("05:30:00 PM"),(D2<=TIMEVALUE("01:30:00 AM"))),"1",
 IF(AND(D2>=TIMEVALUE("01:30:00 AM"),(D2<=TIMEVALUE("09:30:00 AM"))),"2","3"))
```

[image: Excel worksheet showing shift times]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is in your shift definitions. The time `1:30 AM` falls in all three shifts due to the use of less-than-or-equal-to operators. These should be changed to less-than operators, such as the following:

> If Time >= 5:30 PM & < 1:30 AM - 1st shift
>
> If Time >= 1:30 AM & < 9:30 AM - 2nd shift
>
> If Time >= 9:30 AM & < 5:30 PM - 3rd shift (note: I corrected an apparent typo here as well)

The second problem is in the first `if` statement:

```
IF(AND(D2>=TIMEVALUE("05:30:00 PM"),(D2<=TIMEVALUE("01:30:00 AM"))),"1",...)
```

The time can't simultaneously be both greater than `5:30:00 PM` and less than `01:30:00 AM`. Times in Excel are stored as numbers. `TIMEVALUE("1:30 AM")` returns `0.06250` and `TIMEVALUE("5:30 PM")` returns approximately `0.72917`. As a result this `if` statement translates to the following:

```
IF(AND(D2>=0.72917, D2<=0.06250), "1", ...)
```

`D2` cannot be both greater-than-or-equal-to `0.72917` and less-than-or-equal-to `0.06250`. As a result this will always return false.

Try rewriting your code as follows:

```
=IF(D2<TIMEVALUE("1:30 AM"),"1",
    IF(D2<TIMEVALUE("9:30 AM"),"2",
       IF(D2<TIMEVALUE("5:30 PM"),"3","1")))
```

Comment: You are perfect @Brett. Thanks a lot. It working now.